# cant create folder in android

Tags: java, android

i am new to android development and i have a problem in creating folder in my app.
i have searched at internet a lot and i didn't find a solution.
my code is given as below:

```
File folder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "/NewFolder");
boolean success = true;
if (!folder.exists()) 
    success = folder.mkdirs();
if (success) {
// Do something on success
} else {
// Do something else on failure 
}
```

also i added the

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_INTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

and always i get back in `success=false;`

**p.s**
i'm checking my code directly on **galaxy s4 i9505**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just try out as below:

```
File folder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/"+ "NewFolder");
 folder.mkdir();
boolean success = true;
  if (folder.exists()) 
  {
     success=true;
   else{
       success=false;
       folder.mkdirs();
      }
```

As you have provided the two parameter if you use `File(String dir,String name)` then the second parameter is considered as `file name` not folder name. So you need to just use the single parameter to make directory.

You have added the wrong permission in your manifest. Add below permission.

```
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Comment: Downvoter If you know the correct answer then post your answer here. Do not downvote without specifying reason.

Comment: it's still doesn't work. always success return false.

Comment: @user3414609 Check out my updated answer. You have added wrong permission.

Comment: thank you' i just notice now that i put the wrong permission. its working perfectly now.

Answer (score 0):

The Permission is wrong, You are trying to create folder on the External Storage, but the Permission is for Internal Storage.

You should use :

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />`

**Edit:**

For Create Folder use this :

`File folder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator + "New Folder");`

Hope it helps.